# Getting an unauthorized error while PUT request

Tags: javascript, angular, http

As title says getting an unauthorized error although there is a token in request.

[image]

What else can cause this error ?

Here is the request:

```js
editPost(id: string, Post: Post) {
    return this.http.put(environment.apiUrl + '/posts/' + id, Post);
  }
```

It's Angular application, using `ngrx`, if you need more code, I will edit the post..

EDIT:

```js
router.put('/posts/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt'), (req, res) => {

    Post.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, post) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (post.author.equals(req.user._id)) {
            post.title = req.body.title,
                post.content = req.body.content,
                post.postImageUrl = req.body.postImageUrl

            post.save((err, updatedPost) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                else {
                    res.json({ message: 'You have successfully updated your post', success: true });
                }
            });
        } else {

            res.json({ success: false, message: 'You are not allowed to do this.' });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the auth interceptor, I think the problem could be here:

```js
return this.store.select('auth')
            .take(1)
            .switchMap((authState: fromAuth.AuthState) => {
                const copiedReq = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authentication', 'Bearer ' + authState.token) });
                return next.handle(copiedReq);
            })
```

Comment: Please add more details to the question and even add the API you are trying to hit.

Comment: Edited post, API and auth interceptor..

Comment: How are your request Headers configured in your server? You should have something like this `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); ... `

Comment: Since your Authorization is correctly added in your request, it means that a server problem. Can you post some logs of the server handling your request ?

Comment: I have set `app.use(cors())`, accepting all requests, where can I find those logs, should I install some package for it ?